# Is there a bestiary in Castlevania: Circle of the Moon?

Tags: castlevania-circle-of-the-moon

I've been playing Castlevania: Circle of the Moon (the first GBA Castlevania) for a while now and haven't noticed any sort of item or menu option that lets me view a list of defeated enemies, their stats, etc. like in other Castlevania games. Is there a bestiary, or was it not implemented in this game?

Comment: It's been long enough that I can't remember, but I think the answer is 'no'.  I'll pop my copy in and check when I get home if there's been no answer by then.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike many other titles in the Castevania series, Circle of the Moon doesn't have any sort of monster database.

Source:  http://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/449471-castlevania-circle-of-the-moon/faqs/48483